# Derive the price of log contract

Tags: volatility, vix, log-returns, variance-swap

I am reading the Neuberger [[1999]](https://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/%5BJournal%20of%20Portfolio%20Management,%20Neuberger%5D%20The%20Log%20Contract%20-%20A%20New%20Instrument%20to%20Hedge%20Volatility.pdf) Log Contract paper and really confused on the log contract.
So if the payoff is $\ln(S_T)$, then we can easily solve the price of such derivative:
$$f_t^s = e^{-r(T-t)}[\ln(S_t)+(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)]$$
So my question is that when we have log contract whose underlying is $F_t = S_te^{r(T-t)}$, how do we derive the price of derivative with payoff $\ln(F_T)$, as indicated in the paper:
$$f_t^F = \ln(F_t) -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(T-t)$$
It looks like $f_t^F = f_t^se^{r(T-t)}$, but why since natural log is a nonlinear tranformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the Ito lemma, you prove easily that the dynamics of $F_t$ in risk-neutral measure $\Bbb Q$ is
$$
\frac{dF_t}{F_t} =  \sigma dW_t
$$
(the drift is $0\cdot dt$, in stead of $r\cdot dt$ as in the dynamics of $S_t$)

Thus, it suffices to apply the formula of (Neuberger, 1999) to derive the price of the derivative with payoff $\ln (F_T)$ by replacing $r = 0$.

Comment: @noob2  But it suffices to replace $r = 0$ in the formula of (Neuberger, 1999), right?

Comment: @NN2 Thanks, so after we get the $E_t^Q[\ln(F_T)] = \ln(F_t)-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(T-t)$, we discount it back at $r=0$, instead of actual risk free rate $r$?

Comment: @Gunner_ZZ the right hand side of the formula you wrote is **already** the price, so I think the left hand side must be $$E^Q_t(e^{-r(T-t)}\ln(F_t))$$

Comment: @NN2 so if we apply Ito lemma on $\ln F_t$, we have:$$d\ln F_t = -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2dt + \sigma dW_t$$ Integrate both sides from $t$ to $T$, then: $$\ln F_T = \ln F_t  -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(T-t) - \sigma(W_T-W_t) $$ Take expectations on both sides: $$E_t^Q[\ln(F_T)] = \ln(F_t) -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(T-t) $$ why the right hand side is already the price? Don't we need the discount the expectation back to $t$?

Comment: @Gunner_ZZ I didn't calculate the price of the payoff $\ln (S_T)$ or $\ln(F_T)$. but as you wrote in the question, the formula of (Neuberger, 1999) is already the price of $\ln(S_T)$: $$f_t^s = e^{-r(T-t)}[\ln(S_t)+(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)]\tag{1}$$

then the price of the payoff $\ln(F_T)$ must be (also as you wrote in the question)
$\ln(F_t) -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(T-t)$ by the argument I made in the answer.
$$$$
Besides, I think the left hand side of $(1)$ must be  (as $(1)$ is the price of $\ln(S_T)$)
$$E^Q_t[e^{-r(T-t}\ln(S_T)] = e^{-r(T-t)}[\ln(S_t)+(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)]$$

Comment: OK, I got what you are saying. $S_t$ is drifting at $r$ which coincide with risk free rate (and it should be the case under $\mathbb {Q}$). And $F_t$ is drifting at $0$ so we can replace the $r$ in the term $(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)$ with $r=0$. However, I think the $r$ in the $e^{-r(T-t)}$ term is the discounting factor which is risk free rate instead of drift of underlying $S_t$ or $F_t$. So can we replace $r$ in $e^{-r(T-t)}$ with $0$ as well? Or does (Neuberger 1999) live in a $r=0$ world? Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: @Gunner_ZZ I don't have access to the paper (Neuberger, 1999) you mentionned in the question. So sorry I don't know.

Comment: https://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/[Journal%20of%20Portfolio%20Management,%20Neuberger]%20The%20Log%20Contract%20-%20A%20New%20Instrument%20to%20Hedge%20Volatility.pdf    Sorry didn't realize the link doesn't work properly, it doesn't mention risk free rate anywhere in the paper so I will just assume $r=0$